# Page zoomed-in on the iPhone and iPad when shifting from Portrait to Landscape

Tags: ios5, meta-tags

When I change the orientation of my iPad from the portrait to landscape mode my page looks zoomed.

Currently I am using this meta tag in my site
`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0;">`
This allows me to zoom my site on iPad and iPhone but has the zooming problem in orientation.

So I tried using the below mentioned meta tag, here I am not getting the orientation problem but not able to zoom my site.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=1.0, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0;">
```

And I tried all the things which are mentioned in the [link](http://www.ternstyle.us/blog/reset-iphone-zoom-on-orientation-change-to-landscape). Nothing is working for me.

Answer (score 1):

This is a Mobile Safari bug. It was a broadly known issue and has been corrected in iOS 6. Use your previous meta-tag and you should be good now.

http://filamentgroup.com/examples/iosScaleBug/

Also, I strongly advise against using `maximum-scale=1.0`, specially for tablets. This is bad for accessibility, and, quite frankly, an annoying feature.